# Sending cookie from Rails API to Ionic build, Ionic doesn't receive the cookie

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, ionic-framework, rails-api

I am sending a cookie back from a Rails API to an Ionic cell phone app, which for testing purposes I am first running in the browser.

Here is the Rails code in question.

`cookies[:cookie_test] = {
          value: 'cookie received',
          expires: 1.year.from_now,
          domain: :all
        }`

I am using Chrome dev tools to see what cookies are stored, and I can't find the cookie I'm trying to set.

Is there a configuration flag I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are supposed to use cookies when building mobile applications, you should do it through Authorization headers, I explain this further on:

http://apionrails.icalialabs.com/book/chapter_five#cha-chapter_five